# C++ concurrency, synchronization design to avoid multiple execution issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, concurrency

My code calls a function from 3rd party library. Let's call this function `SomeFunc`

```
void SomeFunc(void (*callBack) (int));
```

As you can see SomeFunc takes a callback function parameter. Once SomeFunc is called, the calling thread will progress, and the library will execute the callback several time on a different thread -- passing it different status code.

My requirement is the thread that calls SomeFunc (aka main thread) should wait until certain status code is passed to the callback. So far I have something like this

```
CEvent *pEvt = NULL;

void myCallBack(int code) {
  if(code == SOME_MAGIC_NUM) pEvt->SetEvent(); // signal thread waiting for this event obj they can continue
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  pEvt = new CEvent(FALSE, TRUE);
  SomeFunc(myCallBack); // This doesn't block, main thread will progress to next line
  WaitForSingleObject(pEvt, 5000); // wait here until 3rd party library call myCallBack with code SOME_MAGIC_NUM -- or if it doesn't after 5 seconds, continue

  // do interesting stuff here..

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now this seem fine if I only do this on the main thread / main function like above. However if multiple thread can execute the code block in main above, my problem is they will share reference to the global `pEvt` variable, and it will mess up

What's the best code design approach I should take here? Ideally I would like to change the callback function signature to accept reference to the CEvent object, but since it's a 3rd party library I'm unable to do that.

Comment: It isn't clear as presented: Is `SomeFunc()` spawning your secondary threads and then returning back to its caller (in this case `main()`) ? I only ask because you proposed this in a multi-threaded context, then proceed to show code with no multi-threading at all.

Comment: Correct, SomeFunc() spawned secondary thread -- let's call this "Thread X". And from Thread X it will call myCallBack passing it different code parameter. The main thread and Thread X will execute concurrently, that's why I'm using `WaitForSingleObject(pEvt, 5000)` above to halt the main thread until I'm happy to progress

Comment: May I ask why you would need multiple threads to monitor a single callback event?

Comment: No matter what then, you're introducing a race condition in the followup code. As written there is no guarantee that `main()` will not complete before the thread managed by the library implementing SomeFunc() does. Furthermore, 5000 because...? 4999 wasn't enough and 5001 was just too much? Your comment describing the wait in-code is not accurate. It should read: "wait here until 3rd party library call myCallBack with code SOME_MAGIC_NUM, **or I just don't care after approximately 5 seconds.**" But I postulate you *do* care.

Comment: @jwalk, the code is part of a web service implementation. Everytime a client is making a request, response will be served on a separate worker thread, but I'm afraid the global variable pEvt is shared on all worker thread. If 2 clients are calling the web service simulataneously, the concurrency problem will happen. I've considered passing class member as a callback but C++ has a different function pointer type for that and it won't compile.

Comment: @WhozCraig correct, thanks for that. I have edited the comment on the code to reflect this. The code above is a simpler version so I can easily present the problem. In the real code I throw an error if main thread does not progress after some timeout value

Comment: @gerrytan so is there a reason you need a single global `CEvent`, instead of constructing a new one per-request?  Perhaps I'm unclear on the 3rd-party async operation / what you're trying to achieve by using a shared global?

Comment: @jwalk I can create a new one per request, but I don't know how can I pass the reference to it to the callback function, since the call back function signature is already predefined on a 3rd party library

Answer (score 0):

You really want the equivalent of a closure in javascript. You can accomplish something similar by binding the function call to a new CEvent object every time. Take a look at [std::bind1st](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind1st/) or [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions).

See also this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194119/function-pointers-working-as-closures-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this is the 3rd party provides a way to pass back a 'custom' argument to the callback. Well designed APIs allow to set up a callback *and* a void* value and the callback receives this argument when invoked. From this void* you can expand to anything you like, including objects and method calls, via unsafe casting. All solutions based on binding or member function address or whatever else ultimately boil down to the same issue: somehow the `this*` has to be passed back to the callback.

For an example, see [`BIO_set_callback`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_set_callback.html): it allows you to set the callback *and* a callback arbitrary argument. Note that the callabck argument can be *indirect*, like for example in gnutls: the argument can be set as arbitrary data on the session via `gnutls_session_set_ptr` and then in the callback(s) it can be retrieved using `gnutls_session_get_ptr`. Your 3rd party may provide such an indirect method.

If the library does not offer such feature then you're stranded into hacks. For example you can have a collection of callbacks 'available', each one associated with a specific event (ie. *different* functions as address, although same code). You pick one callback and remove it from collection and place it, then wait for the event associated with *that* callback. When done, place the callback back into the available list. The size of the 'available' list is hard coided at compile time as you really need separate functions, one for each callback.

Comment: Not true. This is what binding is for.

Comment: @hifier: pray tell how does the binding receive the hidden `this*` argument?

Comment: [like this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers).

Comment: That passes `this*` as a copy all the way to the call. **Only works with C++**. Show an example of a plain C callback with the signature `void f(int)`, as in OP.

Comment: ... by "hidden `this*` argument" I assume you're asking how you can bind a functor to method on a specific instance of a class.

Comment: The title of this question is "C++ concurrency, synchronization design to avoid multiple execution issue". Why are we limited to C?

Comment: Because it makes all the difference. If the 3rd party callback signature is `int f(void)` then you cannot give an answer that uses bindings because **it just not going to work**. Is a trivial answer that does not address the real problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27383/discussion-between-hifier-and-remus-rusanu)