# Calling GSL function inside a class in a shared library

Tags: c++, class, shared-libraries, gsl

I'm trying make a shared library in c++ implementing tools for Fermi gases. I'm using the GSL library to solve a function numerically and my code runs without a problem without when running as a script, but when trying to convert it to a shared library and classes I encounter problems.

I've seen similar questions:
[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194119/function-pointers-working-as-closures-in-c)
[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289311/c-function-pointers-with-c11-lambdas)
[Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074756/how-to-avoid-static-member-function-when-using-gsl-with-c/18181494#18181494)

I'm fairly new to c++-programming and cannot seem to adapt the different answers to my problem. Probably since I do not quite understand the answers.

My code is:

```
/* Define structure for the GSL-function: chempot_integrand */
struct chempot_integrand_params { double mu; double T; };

double
ChemicalPotential::chempot_integrand (double x, void * params){
    /* Computes the integrand for the integral used to obtain the chemical potential.
     *
     * This is a GSL-function, which are integrated using gsl_integration_qag.
     */

    // Get input parameters.
    struct chempot_integrand_params * p = (struct chempot_integrand_params *) params;
    double mu = p->mu;
    double T = p->T;

    // Initiate output parameters for GSL-function.
    gsl_sf_result_e10 result;
    int status = gsl_sf_exp_e10_e( ( gsl_pow_2(x) - mu ) / T , &result );

    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS){
        printf ("Fault in calculating exponential function.");
    }

    // Return (double) integrand.
    return (gsl_pow_2(x) / ( 1 + result.val * gsl_sf_pow_int(10,result.e10) ));
}

/* Define structure for the GSL-function: chempot_integration */
struct chempot_integral_params { double T; };

double
ChemicalPotential::chempot_integration (double mu, double T){
    /* Computes the integral used to obtain the chemical potential using the integrand: chempot_integrand.
    */

    // Set input parameters for the integrand: chempot_integrand.
    struct chempot_integrand_params params_integrand = { mu, T };

    // Initiate the numerical integration.
    gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000); // Allocate memory for the numerical integration. Can be made larger if neccessary, REMEMBER to change it in the function call: gsl_integration_qag as well.
    double result, error;
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &ChemicalPotential::chempot_integrand;
    F.params = &params_integrand;

    // Upper limit for integration
    double TOL = 1e-9;
    double upp_lim = - T * gsl_sf_log(TOL) + 10;

    gsl_integration_qag (&F, 0, upp_lim, 1e-12, 1e-12, 1000, 6, w, &result, &error);

    // Free memory used for the integration.
    gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);

    return result;
}
```

and when compiling I get the error

```
error: cannot convert ‘double (Fermi_Gas::ChemicalPotential::*)(double, void*)’ to ‘double (*)(double, void*)’
```

in line

```
F.function = &ChemicalPotential::chempot_integrand;
```

Comment: I suspect your ChemicalPotential::chempot_integrand method must be a static one, if you want to use it as a callback function to GSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed interesting that people ask this over and over again. One reason may be that the proposed solutions are not easy to understand. I for one had problems understanding and implementing them. (the solutions did not work out of the box for me, as you might expect.)

With the help of [tlamadon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423791/tlamadon) I just figured out a solution that may be helpful here as well. Let's see what you guys think.

So just to recap, the problem is that you have a class that contains a member function on which you want to operate with something from the GSL library. Our example is useful if the GSL interface requires a

```
gsl_function F;
```

[see here for a definition.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Providing-the-function-to-solve.html#Providing-the-function-to-solve)

So here is the example class:

```
class MyClass {

    private:
        gsl_f_pars *p;  // not necessary to have as member

    public: 
        double obj(double x, void * pars);  // objective fun
        double GetSolution( void );  
        void setPars( gsl_f_pars * xp ) { p = xp; };
        double getC( void )  ;  // helper fun

};
```

The objective of this exercise is to be able to

1. initiate `MyClass test`,
2. supply it with a paramter struct (or write a corresponding constructor), and
3. call `test.GetSolution()` on it, which should return whatever the GSL function was used for (the minimum of `obj`, a root, the integral or whatever)

The trick is now to put have an element in the parameter `struct gsl_f_pars` which *is a pointer to MyClass*. Here's the struct:

```
struct gsl_f_pars {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    MyClass * pt_MyClass;
};
```

The final piece is to provide a wrapper that will be called inside `MyClass::GetSolution()` (the wrapper is a stand in for the member function `MyClass::obj`, which we cannot just point to with `&obj` inside the class). This wrapper will take the parameter struct, dereference `pt_MyClass` and evaluate `pt_MyClass`'s member `obj`:

```
// Wrapper that points to member function
// Trick: MyClass is an element of the gsl_f_pars struct
// so we can tease the value of the objective function out
// of there.
double gslClassWrapper(double x, void * pp) {
    gsl_f_pars *p = (gsl_f_pars *)pp;
    return p->pt_MyClass->obj(x,p);
}
```

The full example is a bit too long to post here, so I put up a gist. It's a [header file](https://gist.github.com/floswald/7103615) and a [cpp file](https://gist.github.com/floswald/7103639), it should be working wherever you have GSL. Compile and run with

```
g++ MyClass.cpp -lgsl -o test
./test
```

Comment: Like your effort to come with a simpler explanation. In my opinion this is a LOT of extra code that can be implemented in 2 lines using std::bind and the wrapper that you just write once in your life. I truly believe (because I've already implemented this when I was learning c++) that wrapping every single member function with a global function is not only cumbersome but also polute your code with a lot of extra functions (if your code is very big and you need to do this a lot of times)

Comment: Hi @ViniciusMiranda, in this particular example, this is not a lot extra code; in fact, writing your wrapper is more code than writing mine. That said, I'm sure you are right that your way is the "proper" one when it comes to have to do this trick many times in a project. It didn't work for me because I don't use C++11, which your solution makes ample use of. I'm a bit wary of using C++11 functionality because I have to run my stuff on several HPC systems and it's likely i'll find trouble there. I should try out though. thanks for your comment!

Comment: You may be unable to use C+11 today, but you wont come back after you see how powerful it is (the  HPC cluster where I run my programs updates compiler fast ). Example of another situation where how c++11 help you - when I need to allocate a gsl struct (ex: integration workspace), I immediately transfer the pointer to a std::unique_ptr with custom deleter (to teach unique_ptr how to delete the struct). Then, my code is exception safe and I also don't need to delete myself the gsl pointers (you define the custom deleter once in a .hpp). It is almost as good as having garbage collector.

Comment: i completely agree. i dont think i want to/can avoid c++11, but at the moment the cost of learning and persuading the IT crowd to install it are too big. hopefully i'll have time to do that soon. This GSL adventure was pretty difficult for me to understand already, so have to keep learning c++.

Comment: In the mean time, you can use boost::bind to replace std::bind in the example I wrote (boost is pure header library - boost::bind is what I used before c++11)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question. See [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168492/using-gsl-functions-defined-in-a-structure) or [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074756/how-to-avoid-static-member-function-when-using-gsl-with-c) for example. Your problem is the following: you cannot convert pointers to member functions to free function pointers. To solve your problem, there are two options. You can define your member function as static (which is bad in 90% of the case because the member function will not be attached to any instantiation of your class and that is why you can convert it to a free function) or you can use the wrapper [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18181494/2472169) that will use a static member functions under the hood to make your code compatible with gsl without the need of declaring your particular member function static.

EDIT @Florian Oswald. Basically your entire solution can be implemented in 2 lines using std::bind the wrapper I cited before

```
gsl_function_pp Fp( std::bind(&Class::member_function, &(*this),  std::placeholders::_1) );
gsl_function *F = static_cast<gsl_function*>(&Fp);
```

In practice is this is just 1 extra line from a pure C code!

As I stated in a comment, wrapping every member function that you want to integrate using an extra global struct and an extra global function is cumbersome and pollute your code with a lot of extra functions/struct that are completely unnecessary. Why use c++ if we refuse to use the features that make C++ powerful and useful (in comparison to C)?

Another classical Example: if you want to pass a LOT of parameters, use lambda functions (no extra struct or global functions) !!!

To be more precise: Imagine you have 2 parameters (doubles) .

```
 //Declare them (locally) here
   double a1  = ...;
   double a2  = ...;
 // Declare a lambda function that capture all of them by value or reference
 // no need to write another struct with these 2 parameters + class pointer
   auto ptr = [&](double x)->double {/.../};
 // Cast to GSL in 3 lines using the wrapper 
 std::function<double(double)> F1(ptr);
 gsl_function_pp F2(F1);
 gsl_function *F = static_cast<gsl_function*>(&F2);
```

No extra global struct of global functions and no extra wrapper (the same wrapper that solved the problem of integrating member function also solved the problem of integrating a lambda expression). Of course  this is a matter of style in the end, but in the absence of these nice features that allow the use of C libraries without code bloat, I would never leave C.

Comment: Ps: It is interesting that people ask this question over and over again.

Comment: @FlorianOswald hope my edit shows how valuable the wrapper could be